# In the lua source code, why are they using double and not a more generic lua_Number?

Tags: lua, double

In the lua source code, in the file lobject.h in the definition of `TValuefields`, why is `d__` a double and not a more generic `lua_Number`?

The code reads

```
#define TValuefields  \
union { struct { int tt__; Value v__; } i; double d__; } u
```

shouldn't it be?

```
#define TValuefields  \
union { struct { int tt__; Value v__; } i; lua_Number d__; } u
```

Comment: Not sure what you are looking at... old versions maybe? Latest lua (5.2.2) has `#define TValuefields Value value_; int tt_`...

Comment: Same with 5.1.5: `#define TValuefields Value value; int tt` and 5.3-work. Could clarify the Lua version are You referring too? Might it be slightly modified version of Lua engine?

Comment: In Lua 5.2.2, there is `#undef TValuefields` later in the file.

Comment: I'm looking at 5.2.2. the second definition in the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That definition of `TValuefields` is only active when `LUA_NANTRICK` is on. The NaN trick only works for doubles as mentioned in `luaconf.h`.